# React Native installation: Diff between create-react-native-app and react-native-cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a newbie to React Native and I have just started leaning it. During its installation, came across the following commands

- `npm install -g create-react-native-app`
- `npm install -g react-native-cli`

It says that the first one is the easiest way to start building a new React Native application, where as the second is from older mode of installation. How these two ways differ from each other? Which one should be selected especially as a beginner like me to learn React Native? Which one is the best way to install React Native?

Answer (score 2):

The [`create-react-native-app` package](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) is a community-driven package that gives you a basic template for React Native so you can start right away instead of having to set up Babel, Expo (which allows for cross-platform development), etc. It's a great way to start with React Native without having to set up any boilerplate or have an Apple machine for iOS projects. It's a CLI that generates a project for you to start without any hassle.

But `create-react-native-app` has its limitations. The tradeoff is out-of-box ease for less customizability. That's where `react-native-cli` comes in. This is *the CLI* that is used to create new pure React Native projects, run them, etc. This does not include Expo which does not allow for the ease with CRNA nor cross-platform development (you'll have to use an Apple machine for iOS). But with a pure React Native project, you can add native libraries and APIs for your project, which is not possible with CRNA. You can achieve a pure React Native project *from a CRNA project* by ejecting down the line.

I would suggest CRNA as a starting point because it allows you to use Expo to demo your apps on devices quickly and has support for both Android & iOS, regardless if you have Xcode or not -- without any configuration hassle. But it comes with limitations which you can alleviate with ejecting (but will lose other capabilities).